# Send Custom image in Abandoned cart email

Tags: magento-1.9

We are sending abandoned cart email to customers successfully with help of below code. In email we are sending Product image.

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo $this->getImageUrl($item->getProduct(), 100) ?>"/></td>
<td valign="top">
    <p><a href="<?php echo $item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $item->getName() ?></a></p>
    <b><?php echo $this->getFormattedPrice($item->getPrice()) ?></b>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

We are allowing Customer to Upload **Custom image** on [Product Image](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) & once customer Add to cart that product ,  We need to send Custom Image in Abandoned Cart email.

we are using below code for that , but its not sending custom image in email

```
<?php if ($this->getQuoteImage($item)): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getQuoteImage($item) ?>" />
<?php endif ?>
```

we are saving custom image in table : `sales_flat_quote_item_option` & column : `value`

[image]

image is saving in this path : media/custom_options/quote/2/0/image1.png

what i am missing to send custom image in Abandoned cart email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Are you placing the following code in email template?

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo $this->getImageUrl($item->getProduct(), 100) ?>"/></td>
<td valign="top">
    <p><a href="<?php echo $item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $item->getName() ?></a></p>
    <b><?php echo $this->getFormattedPrice($item->getPrice()) ?></b>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```